# Unable to view/edit Dreamweaver files over FTP directly from Filezilla

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver, filezilla

I'm using filezilla latest version and dreamweaver cs6, when I tried to view/edit file in ftp server the file is not loading but when I download the file and I'm trying to edit it it is working fine. I'm using windows 8 os. can any one help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening your 'Settings' dialog and selecting the 'File Editing' page: Edit > Settings > File Editing. Once there select the "Use Custom Editor" option and use the "Browse..." button to select the editor you want to use. Then select the "Always use default editor" option. This worked for me.

Comment: i have tried the above procedure but no change, atlast i had changed the default editor to eclipse then it is working fine..

Comment: Make sure you restart FileZilla after following the steps above, otherwise it wont work.